# Small loop that will determine how much trial it takes to get a success?

Tags: python

Basically, the user will enter a probability of getting success p = .34, so how do I determine the number of trials it takes to get success?

I know that I could get the number of trial by making a counter like n+= 1 but not sure how to use this probability value. Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the trial about? Please give more details on this. We don't know the context you're talking in.

Comment: Do you want the average? The median? A histogram of the distribution?

Comment: So you want the computer to actually run a number of trials with that probability? And see how long it takes? That's very easy but I don't know if its what you want.

Comment: Are you studying Bernoulli distributions?  Do you want to calculate the exact number of expected trials until success, or do you want to simulate it?  Etc ;-)

Comment: I am trying to write a function that accepts a parameter p value between 0 and 1 (can be in decimals). So if the p value is high, there is a higher chance of getting a success. So, I am trying to get how many trials it takes before I get the success. Its like flipping a coin but in this case, the probability is getting success  is modified so its confusing me.@Tim Peters yes Tim, can you elaborate how I should approach?

Comment: Still don't know whether you want to calculate the exact value (no loops needed), or simulate it.  @ShashankGupta gave you code to simulate it.  The exact value is simply 1/p.  If you simulate it many times and average the number of times each takes, you should get a result close to 1/p.

Comment: @TimPeters Well "exact" value is kind of an ambiguous term. You may want to specify that it is the average number of times it will take. After all if we flip a fair coin until we get heads, it can still take an infinitely large number of trials even though the probability is 0.50.

Comment: @ShashankGupta, yes, of course.  Nevertheless, the exact answer remains 1/p, and I explicitly said "average" and "close to" in my comment ;-)  There's nothing ambiguous about the mathematical expectation being 1/p - that's what it is.  Exactly 1/p ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters Totally off-topic but is your name actually Tim Peters or is that a reference to Tim Peters who wrote The Zen of Python?

Comment: LOL - I get that a lot ;-)  And, yes, that's me.  Pleased to meet you :-)

Comment: @TimPeters I'm not sure if I believe you, but okay. Pleased to meet you too!

Comment: Skeptical is better than gullible ;-)

Comment: I'm guessing that he's trying to work on the Bernoulli process problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random()` from the `random` module to generate a floating point value in the range [0,1]. Then you can compare that value to the user-inputted probability. If the random value is *less than* the user's given probability, you have a success.

Once you understand that, all you need is a simple while loop that will keep generating numbers until you get a success.

Here is an example of a function that might do what you want:

```
import random

# The function you wanted

def run_trials(p):
    '''only accepts int or float in range [0.0, 1.0]'''       
    # Count trials
    num_trials = 1
    while True:
        r = random.random()
        if r <= p:
            print "This took", num_trials, "trial(s) to get a success."
            break
        else:
            num_trials += 1


#Input
while True: 
    p = input("Please enter a probability: ")
    if isinstance(p, float) or isinstance(p, int):
        if 0 <= p <= 1:
            break     
run_trials(p) # pass it to the function
```